# Would it be preferable to use statistical imputation instead of a subject matter expert's subjective estimate for missing data?

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

I'm working on a project where I need a variable for the total number of medications a patient is on. The PI is a clinician and I feel they would be able to use the resources at hand - case note and disease data - to make a good estimate at the missing values - of which there are very few ~ 20 for a sample of 500 and another sample of 1700. I thought this might be preferable to assuming that the other variables in the dataset are valid predictors of the number of medications; but, I've had a bit of a look around and couldn't find any studies doing this; should I just opt for a statistical method of imputation?

Answer (score 6):

I would avoid the term "missing data" here.

You are using number of medications as a proxy for disease complexity. For some patients, you can't directly know the number of medications, but you can have a clinician (or better, several clinicians working independently) assess the complexity of the clinical situation and use that information to estimate the number of medications.

I suspect this latter approach would be better than imputation -- provided the clinician(s) estimating the number of medicines are blind to the purpose of the study and the hypothesis you are testing. And much better to average the estimate of several clinicians than just one.

You could test the accuracy of their estimates. Also give those clinicians access to most of the medical records (but not the pharmacy records) of patients for whom you do know the number of medications. Compare the estimates with the real numbers, and report that with the rest of the findings.

Answer (score 2):

My answer to this would be to use the statistical imputation. When explaining results to reviewers or peers, it is much easier to defend a commonly accepted statistical technique rather than one expert's opinion. With imputation, you can cite numerous articles and proofs to support your claims - whereas with the clinician you would have to hope other experts in the same area would just concur. With your sample sizes, I wouldn't be too afraid of wrongly assuming imputed data, you have enough to make reasonably good predictions.

Answer (score 2):

You could combine the 2 approaches by switching to a Bayesian analysis.  Gather the experts estimates of the missing values, then use those to construct priors on the missing values, then fit a Bayesian model.  This will estimate the missing values as a combination of the prior (expert judgement) and what the model fits (like imputation).